# AWS CodeDeploy overwrite existing files when deploying via AutoScaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-auto-scaling

I have an Autoscaling Group that gets scaled/deployed on using `CodeDeploy`, I had created a working instance and got it all up and running and took an image of it for a launch template, this instance was attached to the Autoscaling group and when I deployed it worked perfectly fine.

However, over the weekend, AWS decided to tear that instance down and create a whole new one, and when it did, the deployment failed because of the error `File already exists`. I understand what the error is, but I don't understand why it occurred? That deployment had already occurred on that image, so it shouldn't run into that issue....

Anyways, I know when you manually kick off a deployment, you can opt to `Overwrite existing files` to avoid this error. But I haven't been able to find this setting for when Autoscaling automatically kicks off deployments. How can you allow duplicate files to be overwritten by CodeDeploy when the deployment is kicked off automatically by your Auto Scaling group?

Comment: I'm facing this same issue.  I shouldn't have to remove everything in my ami to ensure that an autoscale works.

Comment: I was able to fix this by removing the project folder in the BeforeInstall script. Not what I was hoping, but it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have specified overwrite in your appspec.yml file

file_exists_behavior: DISALLOW|OVERWRITE|RETAIN

[AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-files.html)